# How to associate more than 1 factor of a variable to the same entry into a data frame?

Tags: r, list, factors

Here is my first question into the Stackoverflow community. First of all, thanks a lot for all the answers that I managed to find here for the past 5 years. You all have been very helpful, but now I failed at finding my answer.

So, here is my situation. Into a bigger data frame, there is one variable causing me trouble: Weather. It is composed of factors defining the weather such as: "Rainy", "Cloudy", "Sunny", etc. My problem is that some entries are defined by more than one factor (e.g. "rainy,foggy"). Thus, R considers these combination of factors as new independent factors, which I don't want.

Here is an example of the data frame:

```
df <- read.table(text =
'"Date.Time","Year","Month","Day","Weekday","Hour","Temperature","Rel.humidity","Wind.dir","Wind.dir2","Wind.speed","Atm.pressure","Weather"
2015-04-01 00:00:00,"2015","4","1","Wednesday","00:00",-3.4,44,30,"NW",10,100.83,"Clear"
2015-04-02 23:00:00,"2015","4","2","Thursday","23:00",3.4,94,36,"N",2,99.8,"Rain,Fog"
2015-05-11 12:00:00,"2015","5","11","Monday","12:00",9.5,93,3,"NE",27,101.5,"Mist,Shower,Fog"',
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ",")
```

My ultimate goal is to be able to, for instance, select only the entries labeled Fog including those that have both Rain and Fog.

My idea for a solution is to appply a character split and insert the result in lists that would be into the Weather variable, but I was unable to do it yet and maybe there is a simpler and fancier.
Here is my naive try to do it:

```
for (i in dim(df)[1]){
  df[i,] <- as.factor(list(strsplit(dda[i,], ",")))
}
```

tldr; I want to convert a factor such as "A,B,C" into multiple factors "A", "B", "C" into the same element (same column, same row of the data frame)

Thanks in advance for your time and do not hesitate to comment the format of my question.

Comment: I don't think you can embed a list of factors within a column of factors, afaik.

Comment: Rather than cause yourself a headache here and in all your downstream code. I suggest you simply split those factors into columns valued TRUE/FALSE. I reckon that at least in this case going wide will be simpler in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Actually, @StephenHenderson's suggestion would be the solution. However, it would make my final data frame way too big. Therefore, I went for another simpler solution for now: ordering the factors according to their level of influence and only consider the most influential factor when there are more than one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- read.table(text =
'"Date.Time","Year","Month","Day","Weekday","Hour","Temperature","Rel.humidity","Wind.dir","Wind.dir2","Wind.speed","Atm.pressure","Weather"
2015-04-01 00:00:00,"2015","4","1","Wednesday","00:00",-3.4,44,30,"NW",10,100.83,"Clear"
2015-04-02 23:00:00,"2015","4","2","Thursday","23:00",3.4,94,36,"N",2,99.8,"Rain,Fog"
2015-05-11 12:00:00,"2015","5","11","Monday","12:00",9.5,93,3,"NE",27,101.5,"Mist,Shower,Fog"',
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ",")
```

Fixing your for loop:

```
df[["Weather_split"]] <- as.list(rep(NA, nrow(df)))
for (i in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
  df[["Weather_split"]][[i]] <- strsplit(df[["Weather"]][[i]], ",")[[1]]
}
```

Same thing, simpler:

```
df[["Weather_split"]] <- strsplit(df[["Weather"]], ",")
str(df$Weather)
# chr [1:3] "Clear" "Rain,Fog" "Mist,Shower,Fog"
str(df$Weather_split)
# List of 3
#  $ : chr "Clear"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "Rain" "Fog"
#  $ : chr [1:3] "Mist" "Shower" "Fog"
```

One step further with @Stephen Henderson's idea:

```
Weather_levels <- unique(unlist(df[["Weather_split"]]))
for (lvl in Weather_levels) {
  df[[lvl]] <- unlist(lapply(df$Weather_split, "%in%", x = lvl))
}

df
#             Date.Time Year Month Day   Weekday  Hour Temperature Rel.humidity Wind.dir Wind.dir2 Wind.speed Atm.pressure         Weather     Weather_split Clear  Rain   Fog  Mist Shower
# 1 2015-04-01 00:00:00 2015     4   1 Wednesday 00:00        -3.4           44       30        NW         10       100.83           Clear             Clear  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  FALSE
# 2 2015-04-02 23:00:00 2015     4   2  Thursday 23:00         3.4           94       36         N          2        99.80        Rain,Fog         Rain, Fog FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  FALSE
# 3 2015-05-11 12:00:00 2015     5  11    Monday 12:00         9.5           93        3        NE         27       101.50 Mist,Shower,Fog Mist, Shower, Fog FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE   TRUE
```

***Edit:***

If, as per your question, you really need factor rather than character vectors, it is entirely feasible:

```
df$Weather_split <- lapply(df$Weather_split, factor, levels = Weather_levels)
df$Weather_split
# [[1]]
# [1] Clear
# Levels: Clear Rain Fog Mist Shower
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] Rain Fog 
# Levels: Clear Rain Fog Mist Shower
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] Mist   Shower Fog   
# Levels: Clear Rain Fog Mist Shower
str(df$Weather_split)
# List of 3
#  $ : Factor w/ 5 levels "Clear","Rain",..: 1
#  $ : Factor w/ 5 levels "Clear","Rain",..: 2 3
#  $ : Factor w/ 5 levels "Clear","Rain",..: 4 5 3
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing my loop and execute @Stephen Henderson's idea! However, the lists produced are not easy to work with (plotting or filtering according to a specific factor...). Hence, either I'll stay with my actual simple solution or go with the multilogical variables.